# MSVC скомпилированный код работает в разы медленней MinGW

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mingw

Результаты ниже. Можно ли еще как то оптимизировать компиляцию MSVC, чтобы достигнуть примерно такой же скорости выполнения программы, как в MinGW. В чем собственно причина, плохой оптимизатор MSVC или какие то дополнительные проверки делают программу столь медленной?

---

- Компилятор: g++ (x86_64-win32-sjlj-rev3, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
  12.1.0
- Компиляция: g++ -O3 main.cpp
- Время выполнения: 18517 ms

---

- Компилятор: Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.33.31629 for x64 (Toolset v143, SDK 10.0.20348.0)
- Компиляция: cl /O2 main.cpp
- Время выполнения: 58144 ms

---

Код:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int cached[6];
int SIZE;

void setSize(int size) {
    SIZE = size;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        cached[i] = pow(3, i);
}

int getMask(const string& guess, const string& answer) {
    int results[6];
    bool visited[6];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        if (guess[i] == answer[i]) {
            results[i] = 2;
            visited[i] = true;
        }
        else {
            results[i] = 0;
            visited[i] = false;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        if (results[i] != 2) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
                if (answer[j] == guess[i] && !visited[j]) {
                    results[i] = 1;
                    visited[j] = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int result = results[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++) {
        result += results[i] * cached[i];
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    setSize(6);

    int sum = 0;
    auto t0 = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    const string word1 = "abcdef";
    const string word2 = "fedcba";
    for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 30000; j++) {
            sum += getMask(word1, word2);
        }
    }
    auto t1 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(t1 - t0).count() << "[ms]" << endl;

    cout << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну например сразу видна ошибка - на каждой итерации при вызове `getMask("abcdef", "fedcba")` неявно создаются временные объекты `::std::string`.

Comment: @user7860670 ну создаются. Так в чем ошибка?

Comment: Неявное создание объектов, особенно с нетривиальными конструкторами и деструкторами, - практически всегда - грубая ошибка. Ну а тут это просто бесполезный оверхед.

Comment: @user7860670 в реальности там передача элементов массива. Для простоты примера передавал литералы. Поправил. Оверхед там небольшой по сравнению с временем выполнения всей программы.

Comment: ¿И что, это изменение на время выполнения никак не повлияло?

Comment: @user7860670 повлияло, 2 секунды. Но если повлияло сдесь (MSVC), то повлияло и там (MinGW). Хотя могло впринципе повлиять только в одном случаи. Но мне нужно не "опитмизировать программу", а разобраться в чем причина медленного исполнения в программе скомпилированной MSVC. Какие то патченные стандартные библиотеки, либо оптимизатор у MinGW лучше и ничего не поделать.

Comment: Попробовал запускать ваш код - отрабатывает тоже за 50+с. Отключил рантайм проверки `/GS-` - стал отрабатывать за 0 секунд.

Comment: Переделав `int volatile sum = 0;` чтобы отключить полную оптимизацию, стало отрабатывать за 40 секунд.

Comment: @user7860670 да, в MinGW тоже при -O3, если убрать sum +=, к примеру, то метод вызываться не будет. В MSVC же, при /O2 вызывается. Поэтому, если время выполнения 0, то это однозначно "оптимизация" компилятора. На рельном примере, где данные прочитываються из файла (20000 элементов), и происходит 20000 * 20000 итераций, время выполнение 12 секунд в MinGW и 32 секунды в MSVC если мне не изменяет память.

Comment: Это код для подсчёта комбинаций в "быки-и-коровы"?